# Can't change preset selections in radio checkbox

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have literally no experience. I'm a paramedic, and I have to fill out hundreds of patients forms using a redundant form with many superfluous fields.

I am trying to write a script to prefill some of the fields that stay the same for most patients, for example, "age units." Almost all of our patient's ages are in "years" but the software fields listed include "minutes, hours, days, weeks, months, years, cancel the selection, etc." The field is required for completion of a report, yet the default is set to "cancel selection", which will prevent completion of the report.

I have attached the code as it is. I literally had to google what (language?) this was even written in. First, I figured that I could inspect the default element, inspect the desired element, and just modify the values so that the desired element was checked. Then, I tried to use an autofill extension that allowed me to select a form field and modify the value. I tried to modify it as a checkbox/radio. I tried to use javascript. I yelled. I have been wildly unsuccessful. If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd be eternally grateful. I don't even know what I'm trying to modify. Is it a radio/checkbox? Is it a button? Is it text?

I have tried as much as my feeble brain is capable of.

This is what one of the offending elements of the form looks like.

```html
<div class="radio_checkbox_div_container">
  <table class="table_radio">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="td_radio ui-state-highlight"><input type="radio" name="ePatient_16" id="ePatient_16_cancel" value="" checked=""> Cancel Selection </td>
        <td colspan="2"> &nbsp; </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="td_radio td_3col"><input type="radio" class="reg_option" name="ePatient_16" id="ePatient_16_0" value="2516001"> Days </td>
        <td class="td_radio td_3col"><input type="radio" class="reg_option" name="ePatient_16" id="ePatient_16_1" value="2516003"> Hours </td>
        <td class="td_radio td_3col"><input type="radio" class="reg_option" name="ePatient_16" id="ePatient_16_2" value="2516005"> Minutes </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="td_radio td_3col"><input type="radio" class="reg_option" name="ePatient_16" id="ePatient_16_3" value="2516007"> Months </td>
        <td class="td_radio td_3col"><input type="radio" class="reg_option" name="ePatient_16" id="ePatient_16_4" value="2516009"> Years </td>
        <td class="td_radio td_3col"><input type="radio" class="nil_option" name="ePatient_16" id="ePatient_16_5" value="7701001"> Not Applicable </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="td_radio td_3col"><input type="radio" class="nil_option" name="ePatient_16" id="ePatient_16_6" value="7701003"> Not Recorded </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I want to modify some form fields (all similar to above) so that my most used selections are the default values.

Comment: I think, you have to make pattern, to make your script work. Like if you want to select radio button with value _cancel Selecttion_ then just press F12 paste the following command and press enter.  Command will run and checkbox will be chec ked `$('#ePatient_16_cancel').attr('checked', 'true')`

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I barely figured out how to get the whole table code to show. I did try what you suggested, supplementing the "years" info and nothing happened.
I put this: $('#ePatient_16_04').attr('checked', 'true') 

and this popped up under it: init {context: document, selector: "#ePatient_16_04"}

Comment: years radio button id is `$("#ePatient_16_4")` not `$("#ePatient_16_04")` yaaaa just zero(0) can change the whole context

Answer (score 0):

He Hi Hello,

I create one jsfiddle for you, just copy paste html tags and replace ids in script to select radio buttons and other elements

this will give you basic idea

https://jsfiddle.net/1efx59vn/

```
<div class="radio_checkbox_div_container"><table class="table_radio"><tbody><tr><td class="td_radio ui-state-highlight"><input type="radio" name="ePatient_16" id="ePatient_16_cancel" value="" > Cancel Selection </td><td colspan="2"> &nbsp; </td></tr>
<script>
$('#ePatient_16_cancel').attr('checked', 'true')
</script>
```

As i can see, you are new, have no knowledge about javascript, so this will be tough for you to understand. But try to understand just few things like in this script tag    `$('#ePatient_16_cancel').attr('checked', 'true')` _ePatient_16_cancel_ is an id of radio button, id means your unique account number, that no one will have, find ids for other elemets too and put inside *$('#')* replace  with element ID.

So the script will look like this 
 `$('#ePatient_16_cancel').attr('checked', 'true')`

open form in chrome browser and press F12 key, navigate to console tab and paste the script in console then press enter, this will select radio button for you

Comment: You did a good job trying to explain the mechanics of JavaScript! To elaborate a little more, you can right click on any radio button, text element, or whatever and choose "Inspect" from the menu. This will open the Developer Tools for your Web browser, which displays the source code of the page. The clicked element will be highlighted, and you can examine it for its ID (and other) properties. You can then copy and paste that ID after the hash mark in the above example; paste that command in the Dev Tools console window and voila! The radio button is checked!